# Isn't answering a duplicate frowned upon?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280047/replace-characters-inside-an-array#55280076) was asked today on S.O. It is clearly, and blatantly a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839401/c-sharp-string-replace)

However, some user answered it anyway (and those user all have at least 1K rep). Even a 61K rep user answered it.

Isn't answering those questions completely contradictory to the principle of flagging duplicates ?

Comment: Oh the irony! A question about dupes gets closed as a dupe.

Comment: The irony would have been that a 999k user answered it here ...